# How to pass data from Blade file to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I know this is how to pass data from blade file to JavaScript?
Is there any other alternative. Because I am trying to avoid script tags in blade file

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var value = {!! $chart_data !!};
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could fetch the data you need from PHP in JS using Ajax?

Comment: maybe you need [@verbatim](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-at-verbatim-directive)

Comment: You are right but i will be using the same script tags for ajax ,Anyways Thanks

Comment: @PavloMezhevikin I will look into verbatim thankyou

Comment: @KickB if it help you, post worked code.. maybe its help someone else

Comment: I will definitely post once I complete @PavloMezhevikin